# Elastic Beanstalk .config file on VCS?

Tags: git, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a Laravel application and I've created a folder .ebextensions where all my .config files are stored.

The project is under VCS using GIT and I'm not sure if i want to add the .config to the repository as it contains some of my credentials.

Can the .config file be moved to s3 and used for deployment ?

Comment: Your `.config` files should be available as `snippets` in the VCS - lacking your credentials of course. Credentials should **never** be stored anywhere, and exist only at 1 given location at a time, sans duplication. However, parameters **without** credentials are *rarely* an issue.

Comment: Ok, I've put the .config files without credentials in VCS, i need to create a file that contain my credentials. How would i do that in EB ?

Comment: And I'm not sure what is meant by `snippets`

Comment: Easiest way is set an environment variable in your elastic beanstalk environment and then you can access those through variables in your config files.

Comment: Yes i have done that but still i need a .env file in my root application folder with these credentials for my application to work since it's based on Laravel Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Elastic beanstalk console

> Configuration > Software Configuration > Environment Properties

You'll see a screen like this

[image]

You can fill in your environment variables here.

This means you don't need to set up environment variables in `.config` files, nor do you need to commit your `.env` file to VCS.

Environment variables entered into the console are copied to any EC2 boxes which elastic beanstalk manages for you within that application/environment.

The .env file in Laravel is designed to facilitate development and as such shouldn't be used in production. Anything in that file should be created as real environment variables and the .env file need not be present.

The .env file (via phpdotenv) simply creates environment variables at runtime, which isn't necessary if the environment variables actually exist already.

Answer (score 2):

Never put credentials and other secret information in VCS/Git.

Ideally, you would put your secrets in some kind of "vault" that your EB application would access at runtime, thus never storing the information itself. However, sometimes this isn't possible/practical.

For Elastic Beanstalk, you can do the following:

1. Create your `.config` file in `.ebextenions`.
2. Add your setting for your secret/credential to the config file with a value such as "change me".
3. After you deploy your application to Elastic Beanstalk, modify your application's configuration "Software" settings, and change the value for your setting from "change me" to an appropriate value.

Comment: All my credentials that are required by Laravel to function are in `.env` file and every time i use `eb deploy` command it is removed since it's not under VCS. and if I do this I'll have to ssh into the instance and update my credentials every time. Can i put my credentials into config.yml or any other place to automate this process with every update.

Comment: No. The data will still be in Git, which you want to avoid. try putting your info into the environment variables controlled by EB. Then when your application starts up, transfer the information from there to your `.env` file.

Comment: I guess as @ben-swinburne points i can save the credentials in Elastic Beanstalk configuration from the console.

Comment: By putting them in the `.ebextensions` file, they setting names will be pre-added to your EB application properties page.